# Does $\sup\limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1}X_{t}$ have the same law as $\sup\limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1}Y_{t}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let two stochastic processes $(X_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ and $(Y_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ that are equal in distribution. For simplicity let's say both are Gaussian processes.

Is it necessarily true that

$\sup\limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1}X_{t}$ has the same law as $\sup\limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1}Y_{t}$?

We know that for any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ we obtain $$ \mathbb P(X_{t} \in A)=\mathbb P(Y_{t} \in A)$$

I am unsure what operations we are allowed to consider on $\sup\limits_{ 0 \leq t \leq 1}X_{t}$ and $\sup\limits_{ 0 \leq t \leq 1}Y_{t}$ since $[0,1]$ is an uncountable set.

Any ideas?

Comment: That inability to transition between a countable set, and $[0,1]$ should prove to be the downfall. I expect a counterexample to your statement.

Comment: Would the fact that $X$ and $Y$ both have continuous sample paths help at all?

Comment: It would massively help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your assumption of sample continuity, these two objects are equal in law.
There are two ways to see it:

- Either you see that  $$\max_{ t \in [0,1]} X_t = \sup_{t \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}^+} X_t$$
- Or, you can argue that $$\begin{align} H :\mathcal{C}([0,1]) &\quad \longrightarrow &   \mathbb{R}\\ \quad f& \quad \longmapsto & \max_{t \in [0,1] } f(t)\end{align}$$
  is a continous function.

Comment: Continuity of paths is not given so this proof does not work.

Comment: but you see, it is given in his comment.

Comment: What is the precise meaning of equal in law?

Comment: Is it some form of sarcasm? As far as I know, it bears the same meaning as convergence in distribution.